# Adding new input fields on check box ticked

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table with 3 text fields
i want to add the same text fields on clicking check box i have the following code
how can i do it with php and javascript

```html
 echo "<td>Screen ".$i."</td>";
                       echo "<td><input type='text' id='filmname".$k."' name='filmname".$k."'value='".$prefilm."'></td>";
                       echo "<td><input type='text' id='Language".$k."' name='Language".$k."'value='".$prelang."'></td>";
                       echo "<td><input type='text' id='showtime".$k."' name='showtime".$k."'value='".$prescreen."'></td>";
                       
 echo "<td ><input type='checkbox' class='Checkbox' id='addshow".$k."' autocomplete='off'
                       name='addshow".$k."' value='addshow' onclick='addshow(".$k.")</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you can clarify where you want to add which text fields when the checkbox got checked.

Two ideas:

1. You can create your text fields at the same time when you create your table and then hide/show them with CSS and JavaScript. (Preferred)
2. Add a click listener to your checkbox and create your text fields dynamically with JS with document.createElement('input') [Learn more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Code examaple for the 2nd option:

```
const check = document.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
      check.addEventListener('click', createTextInput);

function createTextInput() {
  const target = document.querySelector(YOUR TARGET SELECTOR);

  const input = document.createElement('input'); 
        input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        input.addEventListener(OPTIONAL IF YOU WANT)

  target.appendChild(input); // this adds the new input into your target
}
```

Comment: can you please eexplain the second method